# rewrite rule for changing the url for specific extension files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect to a different url for the specific file extensions. Here is the rewrite rule written for the purpose :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost.test.com:90/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This redirects all the files to the http://localhost.test.com:90/ url. Please help me understand what is going wrong with the above rules. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|png|css|js|php)$` without `!`

Comment: Works perfectly fine after removing  !, thanks a lot for the help.